# can't connect to a database remotely on a c# app which i can see by visiting that server's phpmyadmin site

Tags: c#, mysql, server

I have added a database via phpmyadmin on a server. I can access it via http://ipaddress/phpmyadmin . but when i try using those credentials to connect to that db on a c# app , i get the error : unable to retrieve the list of database.

I don't have the right to access the server. I have a user who has rights to two db which i can see when i remotely connect to that server's phpmyadmin. Is it possible that i have right to the db just via phpmyadmin but can't access it via app because i don't have the right to do it because mysql is forbidding it ? I also have a raspberry pi handy. is using it as a db server a better alternative than this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since phpMyAdmin runs on a web server, most people install it on the same machine the database is running on and access it remotely through the network. That means their phpMyAdmin is communicating with MySQL locally, often without the connection leaving the server. Your C# application, on the other hand, is a compiled application that would likely run on your client machine, not the server - meaning any connection from the application to the database is occurring through the network (or internet, depending again on your configuration). Since exposing the MySQL port is generally a bad idea, your MySQL may be configured to only listen locally, or you may have a firewall or NAT connection blocking you from even reaching the server. If that's the case, you may need to rethink how you'll communicate with the database (oftentimes exposing an API is a better solution than opening port 3306 to the world).

It's also possible you're using two different user accounts. To MySQL, an individual user account consists not only of the username, but also the hostname. You can use a wildcard hostname (`%`) which means all hosts, except it's really "all hosts connecting via TCP/IP networking connection."

It's possible that your application and your phpMyAdmin are using two different connection methods; one using TCP/IP and the other using sockets. Check which phpMyAdmin is using (the easiest way to do so is to look at the host phpMyAdmin is connecting to; 'localhost' is a socket connection and '127.0.0.1' is networking). Configure your C# application the same way.